# How can I make changes in an existing NetSuite form or how to write a new form using HTML, Bootstrap & JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, netsuite

I am trying to create new form using **HTML/ JavaScript** in NetSuite.

I read some of the links (Creating Custom HTML Forms in NetSuite on Youtube) which depicted on how to do it, but when I tried on my personal account (administrator) it is not happening, I don't have that **"Marketing Template"** subtab in the Documents Section.

I have also read about the **Suitlets**, but everything is very confusing. These forms are supposed to pop up on NetSuite Window only.

Answer (score 1):

Suitelets are the correct approach to create a new custom page in the NetSuite UI.

You can pull in any custom HTML, CSS, and AMD-compatible JS library you wish. To help more than that, you'll need to ask more detailed questions.

Here's a video showing an example of creating a Suitelet, although it uses the SuiteScript UI APIs rather than custom HTML: https://youtu.be/Hk2lG-SfZ3k

Comment: Thank you so much @erictgrubaugh for a quick reply and your youtube series are of great help. :)
 Actually, I have just started learning about it. I wanted to ask basically is- 
1. can the files should be any format,
2. all the files to be stored in File Cabinet folder.
3. why do we need to use only marketing template every time we need to link a .html file in it?
4. about suitelets- where to create them? It is very confusing! 
(P.S.- I know these questions may sound silly, but I am very new to it!)